# problem building threadx with TX_THREAD_ENABLE_PERFORMANCE_INFO

Tags: threadx

After building thredx with **TX_THREAD_ENABLE_PERFORMANCE_INFO** option and linking to the project the processor hangs up.
It is working fine without this option.
What are the requirements (stack, ram, flash etc.) for this option?

Answer (score 1):

Threadx **and the application** should be compile with **TX_THREAD_ENABLE_PERFORMANCE_INFO** defined

The problem raised because I did not compile the application with **TX_THREAD_ENABLE_PERFORMANCE_INFO** defined (only threadx).

After defining **TX_THREAD_ENABLE_PERFORMANCE_INFO** for the application also, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The size of structures holding data for threads, semaphores and other objects will grow, to accommodate the variables necessary to keep track of the operations monitored. Stack sizes may grow too. The exact numbers will depend on your architecture, compiler, compiler options and other user options of ThreadX. Try increasing the stack sizes that you are using and make sure that the thread/semaphore/etc structures have enough space. You can check the stack size used for each thread in the TX_THREAD structure for each thread directly in the debugger or using the IDEs OS support for ThreadX if available in your tool.